# angular js controller multiple injections

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have built the next controller:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location)
```

now I want to inject something that's called SharedState. tried to:

```
.controller('chatCtrl' ['SharedState', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, SharedState)
```

or:

```
.controller('chatCtrl' ['$scope','SharedState', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function($scope, SharedState, $route, $routeParams, $location)
```

both returns error:

```
Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/ng/areq?p0=myCtrl&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined
```

what is the correct way to achieve injection?

Comment: missing comma after `'chatCtrl'` perhaps?

Comment: I would guess that there may be an issue with the declaration of your SharedState provider? Could you please provide the relevant code for that?

Comment: it does work when not using $route, $routeParams and $location

Comment: .controller('chatCtrl' ['SharedState', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location, SharedState) is definitely wrong

Comment: What does SharedState represent in your code? Comma is also missed as @Aprillion say

Comment: This most probably is because of another piece of code. Your second example looks correct. Can you please post the code for SharedState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my second try:

`.controller('chatCtrl', ['$scope','SharedState', '$route', '$routeParams', '$location', function($scope, SharedState, $route, $routeParams, $location)`

with comma works.

thanks for helping! @Aprillion